# Can some type of matter in its gas phase ever have lower entropy than another type of matter in its liquid phase?

Tags: entropy

I'm trying to deepen my understanding of entropy beyond the overly simplistic analogy with "disorder".

Consider some matter in its gaseous phase that has been cooled to just above its condensation point, so that it has the least amount of entropy possible while still being in the gas phase. Let's call this G. Let's also specify that G has a very low condensation point, ie it remains in the gas phase at a very low temperature, eg helium. (Note that one can supercool the gas below its normal condensation point to lower the entropy even further.)

Then consider some matter in its liquid phase that has been heated to just below its evaporation point, so that it has the greatest amount of entropy possible while still being in the liquid phase. Let's call this L. Let's also specify that L has a very high evaporation point, ie, it remains in the liquid phase at a very high temperature, eg tungsten.

Now compare the entropy of an equal number of moles of G and L.

1. Can it ever be the case that the moles of L can have greater entropy than the moles of G?
2. What are some examples of this phenomenon?
3. Given my two examples, helium and tungsten, is it the case that a
   mole of helium gas at the temperature just above its condensation
   point has lower entropy than a mole of liquid tungsten just below
   its evaporation point?
4. Similarly, can it be true that a liquid phase of matter
   can have lower entropy than the solid phase of some other kind of
   matter (supposing supercooling of the liquid is involved)? Examples?
5. Are there any papers/books/presentations that use this
   "inversion" of the entropies of phases of matter to help illuminate
   the concept of entropy?

Note that this question appears to be related to the concept of [entropy crossing](https://www.princeton.edu/~fhs/paper170/paper170.pdf), where some types of matter can be in a liquid phase that has less entropy than its solid phase. In my question, however, the matter in the two phases can be different.

If the answer to (1) or (3) is yes, then this is yet another example of why the intuition that entropy is equivalent to disorder needs to be overturned.

Comment: Have you found any papers? If you have then it saves us duplicating effort...

Comment: @SolarMike No, I haven't found any papers. That's why I'm asking the question.